# How can I paste a comma (,) in a string of numbers in R Statistics?

Tags: r

I'm quite newbie at R Statistics. I have a vector with multiple objects inside (numbers), and I want to put a comma between the first and second number for the whole objects.

`x` gives this result:

````
  [8] -8196110 -7681989 -8042092 -8196660 -7606310 -7217828 -7634887
 [15] -7401244 -7211947 -7636932 -7606444 -7598894 -7398965```

My question is how to automatically put a comma in all those objects between the first and the second numbers. The desired output would be:

```[1] -8,385772 -7,390682 -8,019960 -8,300000 -8,069984 -8,786782 -7,414995
  [8] -8,196110 -7,681989 -8,042092 -8,196660 -7,606310 -7,217828 -7,634887
 [15] -7,401244 -7,211947 -7,636932 -7,606444 -7,598894 -7,398965```
````

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to capture the first digit from the start (`^`) of the string and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) followed by the`,`

```
sub("^(-?\\d)", "\\1,", x)
```

-output

```
[1] "-8,196110" "-7,681989" "-8,042092" "-8,196660" "-7,606310" "-7,217828" "-7,634887" "-7,401244" "-7,211947" "-7,636932" "-7,606444" "-7,598894" "-7,398965"
```

#### data

```
x <- c(-8196110, -7681989, -8042092, -8196660, -7606310, -7217828, 
-7634887, -7401244, -7211947, -7636932, -7606444, -7598894, -7398965
)
```

Comment: Nice use of the backreference! very cool regex feature

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @akrun. And if I need to put it on the second or the third position?

Comment: @user66349 Then you may change the `\\d` to `\\d{2}`

Answer (score 2):

We can use strsplit to split our numeric vector into a list where each element has the first digit and then the rest of the number. Then pass that into an sapply call that inserts a comma in the right spot:

```
x_split = strsplit(as.character(x), split = '')

sapply(x_split, function(k){paste0(c(k[1], ',',k[2:length(k)]), collapse = '')})
```